# How to set lang="en" outside <HTML>

Tags: html, lang

I have a site that is based on the Smoolis platform.

On the site, I'm validating my code and I am mostly done.
However, W3C Validator gives me a warning that I need to set my lang="en"

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fmax2006.smoolis.com%2F

I'm unable to access the  tag due to the restrictions of the platform.
As such, I have tried using a  ...  around the main body text, but to no avail in removing the warning (presumably because I can still not access all of the material on page via this method.

Is there a way to set the overall page language without accessing the  tag - in a way that W3C will accept?

Or should I just ignore this issue? (seems Smoolis does try to set the language via other methods, but just not getting accepted by W3C).

Thank you!

Comment: You could write some JS that adds the tag for you. Can you execute JS on the page?

Comment: "Warning: This document appears to be written in English. Consider adding lang="en" (or variant) to the html start tag" is not an *error*,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't worry about it. While a part of you likely wants to have a flawless page that has no errors, at the same time if you don't have access to the HTML tag, it doesn't make sense to force a workaround just to remove a small warning.

Answer (score 0):

Change your opening `HTML` tag like below.

```
<html>
```

to

```
<html lang="en">
```

This will remove the below warning from W3C Validator.

> Warning: This document appears to be written in English. Consider adding lang="en" (or variant) to the html start tag"